# Getting nested object properties using recusrsion

Tags: javascript, recursion, underscore.js

Below is my object:

```
var obj = {
    'test': {
        'id1': 1,
        'id2': 2,
        'id3': 3
    }, 'test2': {
        'id4': 4,
        'id5': {
            'id123': 3,
            'id456': 6
        }
    },
    'test3': 45,
    'test4': 55
}
```

I am trying to write a recursive function for getting nested properties in the format like.

```
test.id1, test2.id5.id123 etc...
```

But I am not getting properties which are nested as shown above.

Below is my function

```
function getKey(obj, key) {
    var keyArr = [];
    var newKey = key;
    var data=newKey;

    if (_.isObject(obj[key])) {

      _.each(_.keys(obj[key]), function(singleKey) {
        newKey =  data + '.'+ getKey(obj[key], singleKey);
        return newKey
      });
    }

    return keyArr.length ? keyArr : newKey;   
  }
```

I am calling this function like
var keys = _.keys(obj);
_.each(keys, function(key) {
  getKey(obj, key);
}

Can anyone help with this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `_.each`? It doesn't return anything!

Comment: @Bergi : Can you please suggest some solution ?

Comment: I think you can do this yourself. Try to change the function signature so that `getKeys` takes only a single object and returns an array of joined key strings. You'll probably use two nested loops, one enumerating the object and one looping over the result of the recursive call.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. I will try and let you know...